# Making ImageButton clicks counted does not play sounds anymore

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-mediaplayer

I'm new in android. I've implemented code to play random sounds when clicking an ImageButton, first problem is that it does not play random sounds all the time when button is clicked - it choose one sound and plays only this one, when I press the button next time it plays same sound as the first time when button is clicked - I would make this random every time when button is clicked. Also when I added function which counts how many times this button is clicked, app stopped to play sounds anymore, it only shows how many times my button was clicked, but there is no more audio. Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton soundbutton;

    int[] sounds={R.raw.audi, R.raw.berlin, R.raw.bratanki, R.raw.budzik, R.raw.cztery, R.raw.drzyz, R.raw.dziewczyny, R.raw.emeryt, R.raw.enter, R.raw.faza};
    Random r = new Random();
    //int Low = 0;
    //int High = 9;
    //int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    int rndm = r.nextInt(9);

    int clickcount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //media player

        soundbutton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
        soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        rndm = r.nextInt(9);
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
                    }
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                }



        });

        soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickcount=clickcount+1;
                if(clickcount==1)
                {
                    //first time clicked to do this
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    //check how many times clicked and so on
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text1:"+clickcount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        }


    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set 2 setOnClickListeners on same View .

```
try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();

        }
        rndm = r.nextInt(9);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]);
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

see the code you wrote to set mp will run only when the mp is playing a sound.. I just moved it outside the if.

Comment: True, it was obvious. Thank you for that. So what is the way to count clicks when button is pressed?

Comment: just add the code for that count in the same setOnClickListeners

Comment: @Pawel I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Sure, already did this. Thank you and have a nice day!